# Apache Storm UI window

Tags: apache-storm

In Apache Storm UI, Window specifies The past period of time for which the statistics apply. So it may be 10 mins, 3 hr, 1day. But actually when a topology is running, Is the number of tuples emitted/ transferred be computed using this window time because If I see the actual time 10 mins is quite big but the window shows 10 mins statistics before actual 10 mins which doesn't make sense? 
For Example: emitted = 1764260 tuples, so will the rate of tuples emission is 1764260/600= 9801 tuples/sec?

Answer (score 0):

It does not display the average, it displays the total number of tuples emitted in the last period of time (10 min, 3h or 1 day).

Therefore, if you started the application 2 minutes ago, it will display all tuples emitted the last two minutes and you'll see that the number increases until you get to 10 minutes.

After 10 minutes, it will only show the number of tuples emitted in the last 10 minutes, and not an average of the tuples emitted. So if, for example, you started the application 30 minutes ago, it will display the number of tuples emitted between minutes 20 to 30.

Comment: Ok I understand that but initially when I start the application so I need to run it till 10 mins for getting the initial statistics, after 10 mins we can measure the last 10 minutes statistics right. For initial 10 mins I have to check the uptime for viewing the statistics right.